# Unit Testing based on JNDI , ejb and spring

Tags: spring, junit, ejb, jndi

In my application I am injecting some of services based on EJB with use of Spring IOC through JndiObjectFactoryBean like below mentioned so during run the junit I am getting this exception **"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This JNDI operation is not implemented by the JNDI provider."**

Could some please let me know how I'll configure for Junit.

```
<bean id="xxxMenuItemService"   class="xxxMenuItemServiceyyy">
    <property name="xxxMenuItemDelegator" ref="xxxMenuItemDelegator" /> 
</bean>
<bean id="approveMenuItemServiceRemote"
    class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName"
        value="ejb/XXXXXXXX" />
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the `SimpleNamingContextBuilder` from `org.springframework.mock` as it provides a full context builder where you can bind mock or other objects for use by Spring's JNDI lookup.

One thing to do though is to make sure you build the `SimpleNamingContextBuilder` in the static `@BeforeClass` of JUnit 4.  this means that it is all initialized and waiting *before* the Spring Application Context is started and you won't have any JNDI lookup failures.